# class is not public in package. cannot be called from outside package

Tags: jar, quickblox, android-studio-2.0

I am implementing audio/video call in my android application.
I am getting following error while importing the AppRTCAudioManager class.

com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.AppRTCAudioManager is not public in com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc cannot call from outside package.

How to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

in version 2.5.2 Quickblox Android SDK, added AppRTCAudioManager class to manage audio settings manually, so refer to this link http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Manage_Audio_settings. And also you can look at sample VideoChat http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android